# How can I have same encoded string?

Tags: c#, .net, ruby, oauth, urlencode

I  encoded " Central Time (US & Canada) " with C#.

```
timeZone =Server.UrlEncode ("Central Time (US & Canada)");
```

I want to have the same encoded string with ruby.

Ruby UrlEncode==>   `Central%252BTime%252B%2528US%252B%252526%252BCanada%2529`
.Net UrlEncode twice=> `Central%252bTime%252b%28US%252b%252526%252bCanada%29`
.Net UrlEncode==>     `Central%2BTime%2B%28US%2B%2526%2BCanada%29`

how can I catch the same encoded string?

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like the Ruby output has been encoded twice too. Encoding %2B would result in %252b. Are you sure your Ruby output is correct?

Comment: Are you looking at wanting to save something like TimeZones have you looked at UTC also .Net has a TimeZone Class Check out the MSDN Reference Link and from there I am sure you can utilize a URLEncoding based off of the TimeZone.. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezone.aspx

Comment: Actually I am not. I send my encoded string to a server , and ruby code running on it. But I have to have same encoded string because I use oAuth and oAuth signatures should be same for authorize.Is there Any advice for catch same encoded string with C#?

Comment: @DJKRAZE I do not have any problem with timeZones. Because it can be some other string which is include & % ( ) characters.

Comment: @Digbyswift And if ruby encoded twice, why it is not same with ".Net UrlEncode twice=> Central%252bTime%252b%28US%252b%252526%252bCanada%29"

Comment: Is the result of `Server.UrlEncode ("Central Time (US & Canada)")` _actually_ "Central%2BTime%2B%28US%2B%2526%2BCanada%29" (breakpoint it right there and hover the mouse over timeZone), or did you do something to it between then and displaying it to copy here that might have caused it to be encoded an extra time?

Comment: @Random832 no Server.UrlEncode ("Central Time (US & Canada)")==> "Central+Time+(US+%26+Canada)". However I used oauth class (http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs) , there is a "GenerateSignatureBase" function. and ruby side used a gem (http://oauth.rubyforge.org/) , there is also  "GenerateSignatureBase" function. That functions create some encoded string  for  authorizing. ruby and .net create different encoded strings with this functions.But it should be the same. Above results for GenerateSignatureBase functions.

Comment: What happens if you just pass "Central Time (US & Canada)" - not a pre-encoded version - to each function? As long as you only have a single layer of encoding, it _shouldn't_ actually matter that they're encoded in slightly different ways. If OAuth uses URL-encoded strings, it should be decoding and normalizing them before doing any comparisons (EDIT checked the spec - it doesn't do this... how annoying)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

like this:

```
 public string Encode(string text)
    {

        byte[] myASCIIBytes = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(text);

        byte[] myUTF8Bytes = Encoding.Convert( Encoding.Unicode,UTF8Encoding.UTF8, myASCIIBytes);

        return Encoding.Default.GetString(myUTF8Bytes);
    }

protected string UrlEncodePost(string value)
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char symbol in value)
        {
            if (unreservedChars.IndexOf(symbol) != -1)
            {
                result.Append(symbol);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Append('%' + String.Format("{0:X2}", (int)symbol));
            }
        }

        return result.ToString();
    }



   timeZone = UrlEncodePost(Encode("Central Time (US & Canada)"));
```

And I updated ComputeHash function in the OAuthBase.cs file.
=>

```
 private string ComputeHash(HashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, string data) {
        if (hashAlgorithm == null) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("hashAlgorithm");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data)) {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
        }

        byte[] myBytes = UnicodeEncoding.Unicode.GetBytes(data);

        byte[] myUTF8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Unicode, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, myBytes);

        byte[] hashBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(myUTF8Bytes);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hashBytes);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#encoding_parameters says - essentially, that the result *must* be `Central%20Time%20%28US%20%26%20Canada%29`. None of your examples in the question match this and all of them show symptoms of multiple encoding (with the first encoding step being `Central+Time+(US+%26+Canada)`). Stop calling Server.UrlEncode - and, if you need to, write a custom function that iterates over the characters and follows the spec correctly. For C# you would use a for loop and a stringbuilder - I don't know what the efficient way to do this in ruby is. (It looks like tadman's answer gives a correct result in ruby, but the .NET functions [Uri.EscapeDataString is closest] aren't flexible enough to specify how the parentheses are to be treated, so you'll have to write your own.)

Answer (score 0):

Ruby can encode it without the brackets if you want. You just have to ask nicely. In this case, the option specifies all "non-word" characters (regular expression notation) must be encoded:

```
 URI.encode("Central Time (US & Canada)", /\W/)
 # => "Central%20Time%20%28US%20%26%20Canada%29"
```

I'm not sure why the .Net version encodes space to `+` and then URI encodes that, as that seems broken:

```
 URI.decode('Central%2BTime%2B%28US%2B%2526%2BCanada%29')
 # => "Central+Time+(US+%26+Canada)"
```

Comment: The + is there for historical reasons - the original web query format [for <isindex> pages] used `?a+b%20c+d` for the query we would now write as `a "b c" d`. Eventually that got simplified to simply using + [but not %2B] for space.

Comment: In a query parameter, `+` is supposed to be interpreted as a space character, but `%2B` should be interpreted as a literal plus character, as otherwise there's no way to supply a `+` in the parameter. Something's wrong with the .Net version as far as I can tell.

Comment: It looks like ".Net UrlEncode" is actually encoded twice, and ".Net UrlEncode twice" is actually encoded _three times_ - note the `%252526` in the latter.

Comment: with cgi escape: CGI::escape("Central Time (US & Canada)")
=> "Central+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29"

Comment: Why UrlEncode results are not same? @mustafaturan says "Central+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29" on ruby, tadman says "Central%20Time%20%28US%20%26%20Canada%29" on ruby and .net says Server.UrlEncode ("Central Time (US & Canada)")= Central+Time+(US+%26+Canada)

Comment: `Central+Time+%28US+%26+Canada%29` and `Central%20Time%20%28US%20%26%20Canada%29` are equivalent, where the former is using `+` to represent space, and the latter is using `%20`. The final one is just very lazy escaping with the brackets left in.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT (Removed previous incorrect answer)

Hopefully should work fine.

```
        string s = "Central Time (US & Canada)";


        s = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s,System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        s = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        s = s.Replace("-","%2D");
        s = s.Replace("_","%5F");
        s = s.Replace("!","%21");
        s = s.Replace("*","%2A");
        s = s.Replace("(","%28");
        s = s.Replace(")","%29");
        s = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(s, System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);

        if (s.ToLower() == "Central%252BTime%252B%2528US%252B%252526%252BCanada%2529".ToLower())
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Success");
        }
```

Comment: If you write urlencode triple you can see %252526. I can not apply your code to mine.Because there is a lots of text and it will be not good.

Comment: Ok looking at it a bit more closely. According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.browser.httputility.urlencode(v=vs.95).aspx

The only characters not to be encoded are - _ . ! * ' ( ) so I've changed my example code to match.

Comment: Ok but  I can not use Replace function.Because of Performance. Thx